# Three-position switch to control LED light

Tags: switching, powermosfet

I am trying to design a circuit that allows three configurations with two LEDs with a three-position rocker switch. When the rocker is in:

- Position 1 ON, left light array is on
- Position 2 OFF, both lights are on
- Position 3 ON, right light array is on

I have [played around with Falstad](http://tinyurl.com/2x3my6sk) and came up with the following circuit:

[image]

I have tried to input the LED array's details as well as the MOSFET's, but I can't get them correct.

The whole circuit only uses 0.45 A and 100 V. If both lights turn on, then the LED lights would only get half the power each.

Before I go ahead and order the items and wire them up, would someone be able to help me verify what I am doing is correct?

Comment: the unselected gate is left floating

Comment: Please make your question clearer by marking your diagram with the same terms you are using.  Left and right arrays?  One is above the other.  Position 1?  which light is being fed?   Even so,  @jsatola had a good response.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion but @hacktastical has assume correctly what I am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your circuit in the following way:

- Change your FETs to n-channel
- flip the FETs so that the source ('arrow'+pin) is connected to GND
- use a resistor divider pull-up for each gate (what you have on the switch throw, duplicate it and wire one to each gate)
- Connect the switch throw to GND

With the switch in ‘off’ (center), both FETs will be on. Moving the switch to either side will ground a gate and turn off that FET.

As below ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxABZsQkFIaBTAWjDACgB3SivENXijz4JCIbJz4V6-SdJFi22CiABmHACYAnAPYAHADoBHMHCbKIMSCighiebNGxhC2Qi6utR9ds%20uDezvT%20fPh8qho6Bsam5jb0lihsvrLghNJSIbzWalp6RiaQZuBxULCJAB7ISGBCzhBgCBDKKOZwAGpsAMogGJDKuMqEGQM2ECoAhgA2AM4MNuJcLd6CYoQBK5BsmqtZGNauAcTW3vCb2wd8eztirjZocBIIGKJgRzTP4BsSKHi7%202iXayJABKKRqzVC4JKGQKJRgCDYAHMUj8ssM%20nE2Co%20L9ASirthrGBoEg8JtsRRiKJMH4hDSxESSSAyUj3qJsLcnuyEMcoBJKdSrjy-nwtmy8Vybl4Qg9tpL6ZLXryCg8uENpFd1TjeJsuPLNRl6bqQFrsHhBsMAZtkb1%20hjbQz4nyuBd6YSNcdWRcOey1mIeZiXX6ldcocaLlDgmH%20bUVoqvkGRVIPc7KHA8cmxObU5mzRb6HnU8KJR8jazgqjuLwRvEYwE0lXPspjUsm2CG5sgA)):

[image]

If you're determined to use p-channel FETs (and you might want to so that you’re switching the ‘high’ side), you can 'flip' the circuit like this ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxABZsQkFIaBTAWjDAChsKQAzAdwBMATgHsADgB0AjmDhMuEGJBRQQxPNmjYwhbIR1LWhFe23LdeECgRHzIXF2V8hYqTMhzwK%20opRtTlinorIxRAu0gHHgERCWlZeS8oWF8AD0tIJBliO2JMsGUHLjoAdXEAZwAZAFEAEXKAQQAlRvqATTY0mUyKC20IMAQIQuRIADU2AGUQQlDLPAtrIPnE7gBDABsyhhVsNl47Ql6KLgptcGOoNkFKM%20CbkPxjeEgr%20-OT28eg%20DZGy1mwBcwMRlICuN5KPQ3IkYAg2ABzAL0exIuxoLx7GiEILWLFBDDKF77RZ2PBFbHhcFsbhzCxoOlhel2ahgaBIHzUt5M2zcllspJKBEHCwo2zYdHeTE82Y83FE1EoWahHFGeXK960jVqgEXdVgy77PW6sLAwlSw4a2ymy7XFDLfV2ulfdJwV6Oyy491MqHPTHu-VWi4vRFez3LTCEy6I04hXExywEjGG8OPbC6dIWeVph4i9PYMkG5k2Ask-NU-bxpkk72Y6uPatyzEzBzLZtaps6j5GfUvIA)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is so interesting to see how the n channel could be used like this. I will study both wiring setup.

Comment: The rule of thumb for using FETs as load switches is, if you want to switch low side use an n-FET, high side use a p-FET. In both cases the FET source terminal should be the supply and drain should be the load. (Yes, you can use n-channel to switch high side, but that takes some extra work to make a gate voltage higher than the supply.) Good on you to notice that you need to keep the source-gate voltage to less than 20V.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are switching a load from a positive voltage to GND, consider changing the FETs to n-channel devices.  In this configuration they will be acting as "saturated" switches rather than non-saturated source followers.

Select an n-channel FET rated for at least 150 V and 1 A.

Leave the gate voltage divider and switch as is.

Connect both FET sources to GND.

Connect each drain to one LED array.

Add one 10K resistor from each gate to GND to assure complete turn-off when the switch is in the other positions.